# Python scatter plot 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to do something that I think should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to plot 16 byte values measured over time to see how they change. I'm trying to use a scatter plot to do this with:
x axis being the measurement index
y axis being the index of the byte
and the color indicating the value of the byte.

I have the data stored in a numpy array where data[2][14] would give me the value of the 14th byte in the 2nd measurement.

Every time I try to plot this, I'm getting either:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

Here is the sample test I'm using:

```
import numpy
import numpy.random as nprnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate random measurements
# 10 measurements of 16 byte values
x = numpy.arange(10)
y = numpy.arange(16)
test_data = nprnd.randint(low=0,high=65535, size=(10, 16))

#scatter plot the measurements with
# x - measurement index (0-9 in this case)
# y - byte value index (0-15 in this case) 
# c = test_data[x,y]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=test_data[x][y])
plt.show()
```

I'm sure it is something stupid I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to figure out what.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using a [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to define your point locations, and don't forget to index into your NumPy array properly (with `[x,y]` rather than `[x][y]`):

```
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y,c=test_data[x,y])
plt.show()
```

[image]